# Showing $f$ is not one-to-one using Jacobian

Tags: analysis

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is one-to-one and is continuously differentiable. Then can there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the determinants of jacobian matrices at $x,y$ have opposite signs?

Comment: The Jacobians are n by n matrices.  Are you referring  to the sign of the **determinants** of the Jacobians?

Comment: @user247327 : Yes, that is.

Comment: @user247327  "Jacobian" is most often used for the determinant.  If one means the matrix, one usually says "Jacobian matrix."